# Call setState with Click or Escape Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React Modal that opens and closes via a `handler function`.

I'd like to call that function with either a click event or with the use of the `esc` key for accessibility proposes.

How could I track both events at the same time?

So far I got the `esc` event as:

```
 handleCloseModal = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.setState({ modal: false })
    }
  }
```

But then I lose the click functionality on

```
<Modal 
  onClick={handleCloseModal} 
  role="button" tabIndex={0} 
  onKeyDown={handleCloseModal}
 />
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution can be: Create a separate function to close the Modal. Use that function for onClick and call it when esc key pressed.

Like this:

```
<Modal 
  onClick={handleCloseModal} 
  role="button" tabIndex={0} 
  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
/>

handleKeyDown = event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    handleCloseModal()
  }
}

handleCloseModal = () => this.setState({ modal: false })
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! Let me know if you think if there's anything more optimal than this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to reuse the same close event handler for both `click` and `keydown` event types. One way to distinguish between these two event types would be to detect the `event` object's type via `instanceof` as follows:

```
handleCloseModal = event => {

    // if event is mouse event, handle it accordingly
    if(event instanceof MouseEvent) {

       // if mouse click detected hide the modal
       this.setState({ modal: false })
    }
    // if event is keyboard event, handle it accordingly
    else if(event instanceof KeyboardEvent) {

        // if escape key pressed for keyboard event then hide the modal
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
          this.setState({ modal: false })
        }
    }
}
```